# How to search CSV file from user input on textbox in HTMLand display the result

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I saw the code below in a website and I try to add a search textbox and a button to the HTML with d3 parse. What I want to do is, for a user to search from the textbox, click the button and display the result that matches the user input from the CSV.

Is what I want possible? Right now it directly loads the table which is not what I want. The button's `onclick` is not working... I did try to create a separate .js file but I cannot get it to work with the button. Plus I probably need boolean statement for my javascript to compare user input from csv...

```
   here is the javascript:

   function search()
    {
     d3.text("sampleinventory.csv", function(data) {
     var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);   
     var container = d3.select("body")
        .append("table")    
        .selectAll("tr")
        .data(parsedCSV).enter()
        .append("tr")
        .selectAll("td")
        .data(function(d) { return d; }).enter()
        .append("td")
        .text(function(d) { return d; });
        });
     }

here is the html:

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script src="jljs.js"></script>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: 2px black solid;
            font: 12px sans-serif;
          }

       td {
            border: 1px black solid;
            padding: 5px;
          }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <center>
       <fieldset>
         Search here: <input type="text" id="txtsearch"/> 
           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         <button onclick="search();">Find now</button>
       </fieldset>
  </center>
</body>
```

Comment: where is the `search()` function referenced in the `onclick`

Comment: It was in the jljs.js file that I created. However, I deleted it for the meantime because when I wrote the function search() with the d3 codes inside, it doesn't do anything. So I temporarily place the script in the html body.

Comment: Well the `search(...)` function does not appear to be in your html example above. Please update the question with the missing code.

Comment: Done sir. So how should I go with this? I'm sure that there is a lot of things I'm missing here.. :(